How to determine which eigenvectors of the Lagrangian Hessian are constraints?
I am trying to implement a constrained optimisation algorithm where the constraints are not satisfied at the beginning. I am using a Lagrangian multiplier method:
$$L(x, \lambda) = F(x) - \sum \lambda C_i(x)$$
where $C_i(x)$ is a constraint.
Then I use a partitioned rational function optimisation (with quasi-Newton BFGS updates) to find the stationary points. The paper I am following mentions that - at the desired stationary point, the Lagrangian must be a $m$th order saddle point for $m$ constraints. We then calculate the Lagrangian Hessian:
$$\nabla^2L = 
\begin{pmatrix}
 d^2L/dx_j dx_k & d^2L / dx_j d\lambda_i \\\ d^2L / d\lambda_i dx_j & d^2L / d\lambda_j d\lambda_i \end{pmatrix}$$
(and also the Lagrangian gradient)
So when using quasi-Newton (or P-RFO optimisation), we have to identify which eigenvectors of the Lagrangian Hessian correspond to the constraints and then those eigenvectors have to be followed uphill, while all other eigenvectors are followed downhill (straightforward to do by using two different shift factors).
The question is how to identify the constraint eigenvectors?
If the hessian of the original function $F(x)$ is positive definite, then it is quite clear as the constraint modes usually have negative eigenvalues. However, in my case, there is no guarantee that $F(x)$ will have a positive definite Hessian at the beginning. This means the Lagrangian Hessian can have multiple negative eigenvalues - $m$ of which are constraints and some others are from $F(x)$ (i.e. from the top left block of the Hessian of Lagrangian).
I have read some papers where they say that the constraint directions can be identified by checking the weights of the Lagrangian multipliers in the eigevector. I have tried to implement this by simply taking the sum of the absolute value of the the components of the eigenvectors corresponding to the multipliers - but this does not really work. I am not a mathematician, my background is in theoretical chemistry so it might be that I am missing something obvious. Any advice and preferably a simple explanation is appreciated.
